# where is the memory leak

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, memory-leaks

I have a line of code:

```
CGFloat *components = CGColorGetComponents([color CGColor]);
```

and the analyzer is saying that there is a leak here.
I tried free(components) but the app crashes when I do that.
Is there really a leak here since I didnt allocate anything. I know that CGColorGetComponents returns an array of 3 CGFloat's but when I try to free them it crashes.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you doing the leak analysis against an app on a device or in the simulator?  I've had the analyzer misreport leaks on the simulator.

Comment: running analyzer against device

Comment: The static analyzer is warning you of a leak? Or are you seeing a leak from the leaks instrument?

Comment: Sorry the Instruments leaks does, when i ran it on the device

Comment: It's possible that you're seeing the result of a cache done by UIColor. Or you may be seeing the result of a static memory area, if the CGColorGetComponents() uses something like that to allocate memory for the array. Is the leak cumulative or does it happen only once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [SO #792119](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/792119).

> Declaring the variable does not create the array. In fact, neither does CGColorGetComponents. Whatever created the CGColor object created the array and stored it inside the object; CGColorGetComponents lets you have the pointer to that storage.

In short, do not free your pointer.

You could, however, set it to NULL.

Comment: I understand that since I am not the one that actually allocated the array of CGFloat's it shouldnt be my responsibility to free it. but since I'am getting a leak at that place should I actually allocate my own array and free it after I am done ?

Comment: Only allocate your own array if you need to copy the data.

Comment: As a test, can you create a project with nothing but this `CGColorGetComponents` call in it? See if the analyzer still tells you there is a memory leak. If so, I would suspect `CGColorGetComponents` instead of your code.

Comment: Another idea would be to move `CGColorGetComponents` to a separate function. The idea here is that your analyzer may be using a best guess from the memory address to spot the leak. With `CGColorGetComponents` moved somewhere else, the leak may move. Pointers are nasty to debug.

Comment: I ran it in a clean project and got no leaks. that makes sense since i didnt allocate it but on the other hand it doesnt change the fact that it leaks in my project. I'll see if I can isolate it in its own function

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should pass color.CGColor as argument?
Have a look at this thread: [What does CGColorGetComponents() return?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/792119/what-does-cgcolorgetcomponents-return)

Comment: const CGFloat * CGColorGetComponents (
   CGColorRef color
);
It actually is since its an array of 3 CGFloat's

Comment: color.CGColor is just syntactic sugar for [color CGColor] and gets converted to the latter by the compiler.