# size of an array - iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, c, arrays

I would like to know the size of the array from APIs similar to that of

```
const CGFloat * CGColorGetComponents
```

which return an array. How could I get the size of an array returned by an API in objective C?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does CGColorGetComponents() return?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/792119/what-does-cgcolorgetcomponents-return)

Answer (score 4):

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CGColor/Reference/reference.html

> The size of the array is one more than the number of components of the color space for the color.

For example, if your colour is RGBA, the array will be five `CGFloat` long.

As Dondragmer said, if you're still not sure, pass the `CGColorRef` into `CGColorGetNumberOfComponents` to get the array length.

Answer (score 2):

`CGColorGetComponents` is not Objective-C.  It is **C**, and returns a C-style array pointer.  There is no way to get the size of a C array from itself.  You must obtain that information from other sources.

Where do you find that information?  Open the link to the [CGColor Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CGColor/Reference/reference.html) that Delan Azabani provided.  Find CGColorGetComponents.  What is the very next function named?

In a more general sense, are you sure you need to know the components?  While many older code examples use the function, it is often now possible to pass the `CGColorRef` from a `UIColor`.